# jQuery clash with Revolution Slider

Tags: jquery, conflict

I'm having a conflict with the Revolution Slider purchased from CodeCanyon. I won't post any of the Revolution slider code here so I don't go giving away anything I shouldn't.

I am using the following script for other parts of the site and as soon as I drop the revolution slider in, these scripts (shown below) simply don't work anymore. Remove the slider and they work again. Near as I can tell there is some kind of conflict between the two.

I am very new to jQuery and hoping someone might be able to assist.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

// hide #back-top first
$("a.back-to-top").hide();

// fade in #back-top
$(function () {
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
            $('a.back-to-top').fadeIn();
        } else {
            $('a.back-to-top').fadeOut();
        }
    });

    // scroll body to 0px on click
    $('a.back-to-top').click(function () {
        $('body,html').animate({
            scrollTop: 0
        }, 400);
        return false;
    });
});


// Tooltips
$("a").LiteTooltip(
    { margin:"0",padding:"6" //padding : "5", etc //
});

});
```

---------  EDIT -----------

Ok, I knew it would be difficult without the code... Here it is. I hope this makes things bit clearer.

```
</head>
<body>
   <div id="theme-wrapper">
       <div id="mini-header-wrapper">
          <div class="grid-container mini-header">

          </div>
       </div>

       <div id="nav-header-wrapper">
          <div class="grid-container white-trans-bottom">
             <div class="grid-20 grid-parent">
                 <span style="display:block;line-height:106px;">I am 25% wide</span>
             </div>
             <div class="grid-80 grid-parent">
                 <div id="main-nav">
                 </div>
             </div>
          </div>
       </div>


       <!-- START REVOLUTION SLIDER  -->

       <div id="rev_slider_1_1_wrapper" class="rev_slider_wrapper fullwidthbanner-container" style="margin:0px auto;background-color:#E9E9E9;padding:0px;margin-top:0px;margin-bottom:0px;max-height:650px;">
           <div id="rev_slider_1_1" class="rev_slider fullwidthabanner" style="display:none;max-height:650px;height:650;">                      
               <ul>
                   <li data-transition="fade" data-slotamount="7" data-masterspeed="300" >
                      <img src="/files/4413/8267/6500/bg02.jpg"  alt="the7revbg02" >

                   </li>
                   <li data-transition="fade" data-slotamount="7" data-masterspeed="300" >
                      <img src="/files/4413/8267/6504/bg01.jpg"  alt="the7revbg01" >
                   </li>
               </ul>
               <div class="tp-bannertimer"></div>
           </div>
       </div>               

       <script type="text/javascript">
           var tpj=jQuery;
           tpj.noConflict();
           var revapi1;
           tpj(document).ready(function() {

            if (tpj.fn.cssOriginal != undefined)
                tpj.fn.css = tpj.fn.cssOriginal;

            if(tpj('#rev_slider_1_1').revolution == undefined)
                revslider_showDoubleJqueryError('#rev_slider_1_1');
            else
               revapi1 = tpj('#rev_slider_1_1').show().revolution(
                {
                    delay:9000,
                    startwidth:960,
                    startheight:650,
                    hideThumbs:200,

                    thumbWidth:100,
                    thumbHeight:50,
                    thumbAmount:2,

                    navigationType:"none",
                    navigationArrows:"none",
                    navigationStyle:"round",

                    touchenabled:"on",
                    onHoverStop:"off",

                    navigationHAlign:"center",
                    navigationVAlign:"bottom",
                    navigationHOffset:0,
                    navigationVOffset:20,

                    soloArrowLeftHalign:"left",
                    soloArrowLeftValign:"center",
                    soloArrowLeftHOffset:20,
                    soloArrowLeftVOffset:0,

                    soloArrowRightHalign:"right",
                    soloArrowRightValign:"center",
                    soloArrowRightHOffset:20,
                    soloArrowRightVOffset:0,

                    shadow:0,
                    fullWidth:"on",

                    stopLoop:"off",
                    stopAfterLoops:-1,
                    stopAtSlide:-1,

                    shuffle:"off",

                    hideSliderAtLimit:0,
                    hideCaptionAtLimit:0,
                    hideAllCaptionAtLilmit:0,
                    startWithSlide:0    
                });

            }); //ready

        </script>

                        <!-- END REVOLUTION SLIDER -->

            <div id="main-content-wrapper" style="min-height:1000px;">
            <p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p>
            </div>

            <footer class="grey-strip">
                <div class="grid-container"> 
                            <div class="grid-25">
                                    test
                            </div>
                            <div class="grid-25">
                                testing
                            </div>
                            <div class="grid-25">
                                    test
                            </div>
                            <div class="grid-25">
                                testing
                            </div>
                    </div>
            </footer>
            <footer class="basefooter">
                <div class="grid-container"> 
                            <div class="grid-30 footer-logo">
                                    <a href="#" class="footer-logo"><img src="/themes/nextcode/img/logos/nextcode-footer.png" alt="NextCode Creative Gippsland" /></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="grid-70 mini-nav">
                                <div class="backto-top-btn"><a href="" title="Back to top" class="back-to-top icon-circle-arrow-up icon-2x" data-location="top" data-title="Back to top"></a></div>
                                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Design Services</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Our Work</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Support</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
                </ul>

                            </div>
                    </div>
            </footer>    
</div>


 <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {

// hide #back-top first
jQuery("a.back-to-top").hide();

// fade in #back-top
$(function () {
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
            jQuery('a.back-to-top').fadeIn();
        } else {
            jQuery('a.back-to-top').fadeOut();
        }
    });

    // scroll body to 0px on click
    jQuery('a.back-to-top').click(function () {
        jQuery('body,html').animate({
            scrollTop: 0
        }, 400);
        return false;
    });
});


// Tooltips
jQuery("a").LiteTooltip(
    { margin:"0",padding:"6" //padding : "5", etc //
});

    });
</script>
```

If anyone is able to help with this, I would love a very basic explanation of what I have done wrong. I am struggling my way through learning jQuery and hoping to learn from this 
issue.

Thank you in advance to anyone that takes the time to look at this.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I'm afraid there's just no way we can answer your question with the information available. Unless we can see the whole code, there's no way of telling what the problem might be. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Look for something like `var foo = jQuery;` in the js you're using to invoke your revolution slider, so after this `$` does not refer to jQuery anymore and your existing code may be breaking because of that.

Try replacing `$` with `foo` in your existing js after you paste in the slider js.

So, for example `$(document).ready..` becomes `foo(document).ready..` and so on.